# DjangoRest - It is possible to define multiple create(self, request) in ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have a project which need to perform different create processes of the same Model.

We can achieved this one by creating multiple `ModelViewSet`.

```
class AnimalViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Animal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnimalSerializer

    def create(self, request):
         # just simply create the object...
         pass
```

Endpoint is `POST /api/animal/`

```
class CalvingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # This is called when an animal has successfully delivered its new born..

    queryset = Animal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnimalSerializer

    def create(self, request):
         # define parent animals pregnancy as success
         # and more..
         # finally create the object..
         pass
```

Endpoint is `POST /api/calving/`

**But i prefer not doing so.**

Now it is possible to define multiple `create(self, request)` in a single `ModelViewSet`?

```
class AnimalViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Animal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnimalSerializer

    def create(self, request):
         # just simply create the object...
         pass

    def calving(self, request):
         # create the object..
         # define parent animals pregnancy as success
         # and more..
         pass
```

**By this i can avoid creating another modelviewset for the same Model.**

Endpoint for `create(self, request):` is `POST /api/animal/`.

The problem is i don't have any idea what is the endpoint for `calving(self, request):` without using `@list_route(methods=['post])`

`@list_route(methods=['post'])` may help but i want to make sure there is another right way to do this.

Comment: I've responded to your question in the DRF gitter.  By definition you can't have multiple create methods (how would anyone know what to call).  I think you need to clarify what you are trying to accomplish.  If you just want to "switch" behavior, then pass a paramter (in the url, even), detect that, and then call different versions of "create".  Its easy to see what it does in the source code.

Comment: If you are building REST API then don't think about the models. Think about [resources](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html). I would prefer to create another resource and keep code simple.

Comment: @AndrewBacker what im trying to accomplished is something like the second modelviewset in my question.. the `calving(self, request):` is what i want to call from the url request without using `@list_route(methods=['post'])` but as like you said it is impossible by definition.

Comment: @Raz thanks for the link i must study this thing to better understand the concept of RESTFUL API.